# How to use collection and Initialize them in Oracle PL/SQL Procedure?

Tags: arrays, oracle, plsql

```
DECLARE
    CURSOR cur IS
    SELECT *
    FROM bigdata.controlmcopy;

    TYPE controlmtable IS
        TABLE OF bigdata.controlmcopy%rowtype;
    v controlmtable;

    PROCEDURE ptable(
        formalarray OUT controlmtable
    )AS
    BEGIN
        FOR i IN 1..500 LOOP
            dbms_output.put_line(formalarray(i).jobname);
        END LOOP;
    END;

BEGIN
    OPEN cur;
    FETCH cur BULK COLLECT INTO v LIMIT 500;
    ptable(v);
    CLOSE cur;
END;
```

Hi, I want to know where I need to initialize my nested table 'v' and how out parameter mode works with the collections.
I am getting this error.

```
Error report -
ORA-06531: Reference to uninitialized collection
ORA-06512: at line 15
ORA-06512: at line 22
06531. 00000 -  "Reference to uninitialized collection"
*Cause:    An element or member function of a nested table or varray
           was referenced (where an initialized collection is needed)
           without the collection having been initialized.
*Action:   Initialize the collection with an appropriate constructor
           or whole-object assignment.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
DECLARE
    CURSOR cur IS
    SELECT *
    FROM bigdata.controlmcopy;

    TYPE controlmtable IS TABLE OF bigdata.controlmcopy%rowtype;

    v controlmtable;

    PROCEDURE ptable(
        formalarray IN controlmtable                       -- IN not OUT
    )AS
    BEGIN
        FOR i IN 1..formalarray.COUNT LOOP                 -- Use the size of the collection
            dbms_output.put_line(formalarray(i).jobname);
        END LOOP;
    END;

BEGIN
    OPEN cur;
    FETCH cur BULK COLLECT INTO v LIMIT 500;
    ptable(v);
    CLOSE cur;
END;
/
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=355bf816f7ee6cf9a63d3979d9d6df7c)

---

> Actually I want to use collection v as out parameter aliased as formalarray.

Then, you need to generate the values of the collection inside the procedure and output them (rather than generating them outside the procedure and inputting them):

```sql
DECLARE
  TYPE controlmtable IS TABLE OF controlmcopy%rowtype;
  v controlmtable;

  PROCEDURE ptable(
    formalarray OUT controlmtable
  )
  AS
    CURSOR cur IS
      SELECT *
      FROM controlmcopy;
  BEGIN
    OPEN cur;
    FETCH cur BULK COLLECT INTO formalarray LIMIT 500;
    CLOSE cur;
  END;
BEGIN
  ptable(v);
  FOR i IN 1 .. v.COUNT LOOP
    dbms_output.put_line( v(i).jobname );
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=bf5cecd40ca19ba98625dda87c4c0efc)

Answer (score 0):

I don't have your tables so I used Scott's EMP instead. Should be like this (I marked errors you made as comments):

```
SQL> set serveroutput on;
SQL> DECLARE
  2      CURSOR cur IS
  3      SELECT *
  4      FROM emp;
  5
  6      TYPE controlmtable IS
  7          TABLE OF emp%rowtype;
  8      v controlmtable := controlmtable();        --> initialized like this
  9
 10      PROCEDURE ptable(
 11          formalarray IN controlmtable           --> IN, not OUT
 12      )AS
 13      BEGIN
 14          FOR i IN 1..formalarray.count LOOP     --> not "500" as hardcoded value but array.COUNT
 15              dbms_output.put_line(formalarray(i).job);
 16          END LOOP;
 17      END;
 18
 19  BEGIN
 20      OPEN cur;
 21      FETCH cur BULK COLLECT INTO v LIMIT 500;
 22      ptable(v);
 23      CLOSE cur;
 24  END;
 25  /
CLERK
SALESMAN
SALESMAN
MANAGER
SALESMAN
MANAGER
MANAGER
ANALYST
PRESIDENT
SALESMAN
CLERK
CLERK
ANALYST
CLERK

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Comment: Actually I want to use collection v as out parameter aliased as formalarray.

Comment: You do not need to initialize the collection.

Comment: Could you please make changes to my code with out parameter mode. It will be a great help.

Comment: What *OUT* parameter? You're calling a procedure and passing parameter *to it*, not getting it *from* the procedure.